# Can a soul that is normally freed from the Edo Tensei be resurrected again?

Tags: naruto

This Edo Tensei looks pretty complicated and annoying, since the revived one is immortal and powerful. As we've seen, every soul was freed and moved to the afterlife (by this I mean normally freed from the jutsu), so if someone decides to use this jutsu again, could it be possible to bring back again a dead person (meaning that until you run out of DNA samples and vessels, you can bring back anyone an infinite number of times)?

Being an exception, I'm not reading the manga, but unfortunately I know that the Hokage's are revived, and in the cases of Hashirama and Tobirama, they were revived a second time, BUT they were sealed in the Shinigami, so their souls aren't brought back from the pure world (again, I have no idea about their second arrival, please, no spoiler, just I've mentioned that they came from somewhere else).

So for example, could be Itachi brought back again and again with the Edo Tensei, or after his first revival and after his soul sealed, his soul would be "blocked" somewhere in the pure world, forbidding another resurrection of that soul?

Comment: souls like that of sasori cant be called back again. they are not bound to mortal world now. they don't have any purpose now. as for itachi i guess he can be called again, but then again edo tensei is known to only one living person now(orochimaru). so chances of endless resurrection is not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to answer your question, whether a freed soul from ET may be resurrected again or not, I will those points which has been aired on telly so far.

Yes, you can resurrect it.

Before I answer this question, you need to understand how ET works. For this, please refer [**here**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/6537/does-the-edo-tensei-caster-need-to-know-all-the-hand-seals-to-use-the-reanimated/6539#6539). Since you specifically said not to use any spoilers, you can visit the link which I shared.

For more proof, visit [Edo Tensei wiki page](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Summoning:_Impure_World_Reincarnation). They did mention that:

> It is possible for a reincarnated shinobi to be revived into a real living body again. Madara, however, was resurrected without his original eyes, having died without them.